# How to embed angular2 component in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, single-page-application

I have .netCore/angular2 shop SPA app.

There seems to  be 2 ways to  layout 90% of the page html 'template':

- app.component.html or
- _Layout.cshtml

I've gone with _Layout.cshtml which has the  @RenderBody() tag to  display the angular stuff.

In this _Layout.cshtml how can I embed one of my angular2 components. e.g the CartSummaryComponent.

```
  <ul class="userMenu">
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    <li class="pull-right"><CartSummaryComponent></CartSummaryComponent></li>
 </ul>
```

The CartSummaryComponent works ok when in the app.component.html template but I need it in the _LoginPartial.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. Had to  put all the cart summery stuff (3 items etc) out on the main .net _layout. So  when the page loads, these little tags (3 items) were written by the controller in .net/@razor.  Then f somebody added an item to  cart while I was on a 'angular' page, I would simply use JavaScript to  update the '3 items' to  4 Items both visually changing the text on the page and calling a little ajax to  change the 'real' cart on the server.